# Bootstrap - wrong width and alignment to an input tag inside a table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I put input tags inside a table and I found it's hard to control cell's width and input's alignment.

Here's my code snippet:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="./">
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-md-1">ID</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Column A</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Column B</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Column C</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Column D</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Correction</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>A1</td>
          <td class="text-right">B1</td>
          <td class="text-right">C1</td>
          <td class="text-right">90</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="correction1" class="col-md-5 text-right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>A2</td>
          <td class="text-right">B2</td>
          <td class="text-right">C2</td>
          <td class="text-right">50</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="correction2" class="col-md-5 text-right"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
```

I would like the input tag's cells (Column name 'Correction') have the same width with Column D. And also put right alignment to the input tags.

Comment: What have you tried? It's easy to control `input` width using CSS (`width:123px;`) and add the `text-right` class to the containing table cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is assign some widths and float the `input` to the right. Using column classes or text alignment as you've tried won't work.

```css
.float-right{float: right;}
table input{width: 50%;}
table td{width: 10%;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="./">
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-md-1">ID</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Column A</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Column B</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Column C</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Column D</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Correction</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>A1</td>
          <td class="text-right">B1</td>
          <td class="text-right">C1</td>
          <td class="text-right">90</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="correction1" class="float-right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>A2</td>
          <td class="text-right">B2</td>
          <td class="text-right">C2</td>
          <td class="text-right">50</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="correction2" class="float-right"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: I choose this as my answer while answer from @jfeferman has both same solution, Serg Chernata's answer uses percentage to modify, which I preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can try overriding your input style attributes as in the snippet below. Also, if you set the input to `display:block` and `margin-left:auto`, it will align to the right.

```css
input.col-md-5.text-right {
    width: 70px;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="./">
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-md-1">ID</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Column A</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Column B</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Column C</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Column D</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Correction</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>A1</td>
          <td class="text-right">B1</td>
          <td class="text-right">C1</td>
          <td class="text-right">90</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="correction1" class="col-md-5 text-right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>A2</td>
          <td class="text-right">B2</td>
          <td class="text-right">C2</td>
          <td class="text-right">50</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="correction2" class="col-md-5 text-right"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
```